# Validating Ajax loaded form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

I've tried searching everywhere(the past 2 hours), and I've tried all these different solutions and nothing has worked for me thus far. So I thought I would come here and ask the geniuses that be. Since my Jquery isn't very good. I know it has something to do with id's and such not loaded when the script is up, but I don't know how to go about fixing this. 
The code I'm about to show I'm certain isn't the best. I've only been doing this for a few months. So please be patient with me.

Below is the main.php file:

```
echo "<div class=\"main_menu_buttons\">";
echo "<table id=\"nav\">";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo "<ul id=\"nav\">";
echo "<li><button class=\"pm_button\" onclick=\"masspm('new', 'menu')\">New</button></li>";
echo "<li><button class=\"pm_button\" onclick=\"masspm('edit', 'menu')\">Edit</button></li>";
echo "<li><button class=\"pm_button\" onclick=\"masspm('view', 'menu')\">View</button></li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<span id=\"wait_1\" style=\"display: none;\">";
echo "<img alt=\"Please Wait\" src=\"/opserv/regimental/ajax-loader.gif\"/>";
echo "</span>";
echo "<span id=\"result_1\">";
// This is the default load screen. This will change every time we click a button.  
echo "<div class=\"editor\">";
echo "<br><span class=\"header\">List of your PM groups:</span><br>";
$resultVB = $mysqliVB->query("my query");
if ($resultVB->num_rows > 0){
    while ($rowVB = $resultVB->fetch_assoc()){
        echo " - ".$rowVB['name']."<br>";
    }
}else{
    echo " - You have no groups.<br>";
}
echo "</div>";
// End of Default Load screen   
echo "</span>";
-------
//Here is the script for loading ajax
<script type="text/javascript">
function masspm(type, arg, global) {
$('#wait_1').hide();
$('#wait_1').show();
$('#result_1').hide();
    $.get("/forum/opserv/ajaxselect.php", {
    func: type,
    drop_var: arg
    }, function(response){
    $('#result_1').fadeOut();
    setTimeout("finishAjax('result_1', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
});
    return false;
}

function finishAjax(id, response) {
$('#wait_1').hide();
$('#result_1').show();
$('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
$('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
</script>
```

I used to have the validation file in this file. But was told not to put it in this file and use it in my ajax called file which is ajaxselect.php
Now here is the ajaxselect.php

```
echo "<div class=\"editor\">";
echo "<br><span class=\"header\">Create New PM Group:</span><br>";
echo "<form name=\"new\" action=\"/forum/opserv/addon_pmgroup.php?op=addpmgroup\" method=\"post\" onSubmit=\"return validate();\">";
echo "Group Name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\"><br><br>";
echo "<table border=1 class=\"pmTable\"><tbody><tr>";
$i = 0;
while ($rowVB = $resultVB->fetch_assoc()){
    if ($i > $rows){
        echo "</td><td>";
        $i = 0;
    }elseif ($i == 0){
        echo "<td>";
    }
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"member".$rowVB['userid']."\" name=\"members[]\" class=\"aar-checkbox\" value=\"".$rowVB['userid']."\"/><label for=\"member".$rowVB['userid']."\" class=\"aar-label\"></label> ".$rowVB['username']."<br>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
echo "<br><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" id=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</div>";
```

And then here I have the validation script which is also in the ajaxselect.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
msg = ""
if(document.new.name.value.length < 3){
    msg += "Please enter a valid name\n";
}

if ($("#new input:checkbox:checked").length == 0) {
    msg += "Please select a member\n";
}

if ($("#new input:checkbox:checked").length > 30 ) {
    msg += "You many only have 30 members per group\n";
}

if(msg != ""){
    alert(msg);
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
}
</script>
```

I'm pretty sure its possible, but I'm lost as to how to make it actually validate the info.
If someone would be so kind, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? Isn't the validation firing? Did you check the browser's console for Javascript errors?

Comment: There are no errors :(. I've read that there is something to do with changing the way validation is called to be called by the submit button on live, but I've no idea how to do that.

Comment: When I click submit button. The form executes like it shout (Without validation) and moves on. Everything works except when I try to stop a user from entering nothing for a name. It still just submits.

Comment: I think the problem is in the first if condition in the validate() function. `document.new.name.value.length`. Can you change it and select the element with jQuery (eg: $("#IdOfElement").val().length )

Comment: OK I figured it out.. Finally!!! I had to change my above code from onsubmit="return validate();" 
to 
onsubmit="return validate(this);"

And in the validate function. I had to change 
function validate(){ 
to 
function validate(form){ 
and the line 
if(document.new.name.value.length < 3){ 
had to be changed to 
if(form.name.value.length < 3){

I also had to move the validation script back to the main.php unlike what I was told.

Comment: Dola I wanted to thank you. It was your confidence that what I had done was pretty close to correct without very close inspection that I kept trying. I knew it had to be something small I was missing.

Comment: I am glad your problem is resolved. But I suggest to keep your code consistent. In other words, You are using jQuery to select and validate the other inputs in the form (i.e checkboxes). So, it would be better to also select and check the value in the text field using jQuery so your code would be more maintainable and readable. And in that case you wouldn't have to pass `this` as a parameter to the `validate()` function.

Comment: How would I do that? Could you give me an example? I merely searched for a way to check if something was checked in jquery. I admit its a very band-aid solution. But I merely search for answers that work. And I'm certain as I go along I'm just digging myself a deeper hole like you mentioned.